# How to print the line that matches my text using find in linux?

Tags: linux, find, printing

Hello I am using this command to find text within files in linux

```
find ./ -type f -exec grep -l "Text To Find" {} \;
```

The command works fine, but I would like to print automatically the line that contains the text or if it is possible the firs two lines above the text and the two lines behind the text.

Also another suggestions to find text and print the lines instead of using **find** are welcome,

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
find ./ -type f -exec grep -Hn "Text To Find" {} \;
```

Use -A and -B flags to print lines before and after the match:

```
find ./ -type f -exec grep -Hn -A1 -B1 "Text To Find" {} \;
```

also you can just use grep:

```
grep -R -Hn -A1 -B1 "Text To Find" *
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not just grep?

```
grep -r -C2 "Text To Find" *
```

Comment: Because the `-r` option is not portable (as a matter of fact neither is `-C` but hey, he asked for it. :) )

Comment: The poster did say "Also another suggestions to find text and print the lines instead of using find are welcome" and tagged the question "linux", so GNU grep is probably fine.

Answer (score 4):

You may use the following alternate `find` construct for a faster search:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -Hn -C2 "Text To Find"
```

Instead of invoking `grep` for each and every file (which is what `-exec ... {}` does), it will invoke `grep` for bunches of files.

Note that the `-print0`, `-0` and `-C2` options are not portable (will work fine with the GNU variants of the `find`, `xargs` and `grep` programs i.e. most Linux, BSD etc. installations as well as Cygwin and MinGW, but do not expect them to work with "older" Solaris, HPUX etc. installs.)

Comment: And be sure to use "-print0" for find and "-0" on xargs.  This will help with files that have spaces in their names by using NULL as a delimiter rather than spaces.

Answer (score 1):

To print the lines (with the file that contains it):

> `find . -type f -exec grep "text" {} /dev/null \;`

To see 2 lines following the line that matches add `-A2` after "grep" in the above line, `-B2` for the two lines before, and `-C2` for both.

Answer (score 1):

```
find ./ -type f -exec egrep -H -B 2 -A 2 "Text" '{}' ';'
```